# Angular2 nested *ngIf and *ngFor populates same value for iterated input field

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have old template in Angularjs which is as following:

```
    <div class="col col-50" align="left" ng-if="enterTextViewRight"> <!-- enterTextViewRight -->  
        <div ng-repeat="item in randomWord_pair" id="list_two">
            <div style="border:1px dotted gray; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; font-size:15px;height:50px;">
                <input style="margin:0px;" placeholder="Type here" ng-model="pair" type="text" ng-change="rightPartnerCheck(pair,item.word)" />
                <span style="float:right; margin-top: -30px;" ng-show="showPartner[pair]" align="right"><i class="ion-checkmark myCheckmark"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I changed this to Angular2 like this:

```
<div class="col col-50" align="left" *ngIf="enterTextViewRight"> <!-- enterTextViewRight -->
    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="randomWord_pair" let-item>  
        <div id="list_two">
            <div style="border:1px dotted gray; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; font-size:15px;height:50px;">
                <input style="margin:0px;" placeholder="Type here" [(ngModel)]="pair" type="text" (ngModelChange)="rightPartnerCheck(pair,item.word)" />
                <span style="float:right; margin-top: -30px;" *ngIf="showPartner[pair]" align="right"><ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

However when I start typing in the first input box all the three (i.e. as per the number of elements in array) are populated with the same value.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I also tried following but, the same problem:

```
    <div class="col col-50" align="left" *ngIf="enterTextViewRight"> <!-- enterTextViewRight -->
        <ng-container>  
            <div *ngFor="let item of randomWord_pair" id="list_two">
                <div style="border:1px dotted gray; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; font-size:15px;height:50px;">
                    <input style="margin:0px;" placeholder="Type here" [(ngModel)]="pair" type="text" (ngModelChange)="rightPartnerCheck(pair,item.word)" />
                    <span style="float:right; margin-top: -30px;" *ngIf="showPartner[pair]" align="right"><ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Some additional info:

```
randomWord_pair: any;
/* Word pairs those will be presented to the user */
word_pair = [

{'word':'Angst', 'pair':'Butter'},
{'word':'Ball', 'pair':'Faden'},
{'word':'Fluss', 'pair':'Geld'},
{'word':'Kissen', 'pair':'Messe'},
{'word':'Glas', 'pair':'Hals'},
{'word':'Berg', 'pair':'Dose'},
{'word':'Kuchen', 'pair':'Messer'},
{'word':'Ferien', 'pair':'Herz'},
{'word':'Nacht', 'pair':'Pilz'},
{'word':'Rahmen', 'pair':'Sache'},
{'word':'Tür', 'pair':'Sonne'},
{'word':'Scheibe', 'pair':'Wort'}

]
```

randomWord_pair[] contains some of these elements

```
rightPartnerCheck(p,i_p){
    console.log("right partner check")
    console.log(p + " " + i_p)

    if(this.rightPartnerCheckList[i_p] == p){
        this.showPartner[p] = true;
        if(this.enteredSequence.indexOf(p)==-1){
            this.enteredSequence.push(p)
            console.log(this.enteredSequence)
            console.log("Entered sequence: ")
            console.log(this.enteredSequence)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE3** Screenshot for original code (All Input boxes show same value, however whateven Text enter in each box is being entered in the desired array)

[image]

Comment: Seems angularjs and angular2 code is switched.

Comment: You can use `<ng-container>` instead of `<template>` then you can use the same `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` syntax like when you add it to a normal element (like a `<div>`)

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I will update my question

Comment: You mentioned an error in the title but the question doesn't contain an error message.

Comment: I would assume all three are populated since the ngModel is the same, i.e `pair`.

Comment: How to fix the `same model` in this case? The angularjs code works, but the angular2 version doesn't

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried your suggestion as I have updated in my question, but Iam still facing the same problem

Comment: What if you change `[(ngModel)]="pair"` to `[(ngModel)]="item"`?

Comment: That gives me `Cannot assign to a reference or variable!` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use `$event` and capture the value of the input field:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="rightPartnerCheck($event, item.word)" />
```

and TS:

```
rightPartnerCheck(event, word) {
  console.log(event.target.value, word);
}
```

Comment: so removing model completely?

Comment: Well, yes, if you have it there, this won't work. Because currently pair is the same for all input fields so the value will be same. But what is this `pair` and how is it related to `item`? Might be helpful to know, so that possibly could be a "better" solution...

Comment: I have updated my question :) And this solution gave me error, removing model and instead sending error

Comment: Well it should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/eAZ9IlgdSTB49rjD8FRc?p=preview

Comment: Seeing now how pair and word is related, I would actually say that my solution would be the best that at least I can think of. One option would be is to create a new property to your object which you then can use in ngModel, but that means modifying your array, and if you don't need this property for anything else, it might be just unneccessary too.... http://plnkr.co/edit/MEvw8v8ArHpV4qlKrNKY?p=preview

Comment: Oh it worked. I had a small stupid error: there was no space between `$event and item.word`. But then- my checkmarks wouldn't work anymore because they are using `*ngIf="showPartner[pair]"`in the below span. How can I replace pair in there? $event.target.value?

Comment: I figured it out. I used #pair in input and then `*ngIf="showPartner[pair.value]"` in span. Thanks a lot for your answer. It was kinda tricky how angular1 and angular2 work

Comment: Great that you figured it out! I bet it's a bit tricky having used angularJS as well and transitioning over to ng2. I know nothing about AngularJS, but it's surely quite different from ng2 :)